# Issues with Jquery/PHP ajax form submission

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using the following code to post form data to a php file..

```
jQuery("#form-submit").click(function(data){ 

                var url = "save-data.php";

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: jQuery('#my-form').serialize(),
                    url: url,
                    cache : "false",
                    success: function(data){
                        jQuery("#dl-message").html(data);
                        jQuery("#dl-message").css('background-color', '#0C3');
                        jQuery('#dl-message').slideToggle('slow', function() {
                            jQuery('#dl-message').delay(2000).slideToggle('slow', function() {
                                //Animation Complete
                            });
                        });

                    },
                    error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        jQuery("#dl-message").html('There was an error saving your form: ' + errorThrown);
                        jQuery("#dl-message").css('background-color', '#F33');
                        jQuery('#dl-message').slideToggle('slow', function() {
                            jQuery('#dl-message').delay(2000).slideToggle('slow', function() {
                                //Animation Complete
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
```

and then in my php file I am simply looking for $_POST['field-name'] to see if the contents of the form were posted.  The ajax call returns successful, however no data from the form seems to be posted to the PHP file.  When I call...

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "Your name is: " . $name;
```

I get nothing....   Does anyone see anything wrong with my ajax call at all?

Thanks so much for your time...

Comment: what happens if you `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: what does `#my-form` contain?

Comment: When I do print_r($_POST); I get an empty array:    

#my-form is an html form with two selects and an input.  :)    Thanks for your replies folks.  I appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: I put print_r($_POST); in the save-data.php and it returned:  

Array();

Comment: try removin `data` from the click function so it reads `jQuery("#form-submit").click(function(){ `, it may be tampering with your success data

Comment: what Liam said + it seems you don't have a 'name' object in your post/serialized form

Comment: No dice..  Good eye though..  Still gives me an empty array.  :)

Comment: There is an input field with the name 'name' in the form.

Comment: could you print out jQuery('#my-form').serialize() to the browser's console right before you do the post and include the result here?

Comment: okay so I did this...

Comment: console.log("BEGIN TEST");
     console.log(jQuery('#my-form').serialize());
     console.log("END TEST");

Comment: And got nothing in between begin test and end test

Comment: So it seems the post was empty at the first place (btw you can include your last three posts inside the question by editing it). Are you sure your form's id is 'my-form'? The source of the problem of the error may be somewhere in the html, could you also include your form or some reference to it (link/fiddle)?

Comment: HAHAHAHA.. Sorry to waste your time folks.  I just realized that in the id for my form I had a # in front of the id.   so my form looked like this <form id="#my-form"></form>

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the post was empty at the first place (btw you can include your last three posts inside the question by editing it). Are you sure your form's id is 'my-form'?

Comment: @user2612819 can you close your question eg by accepting an answer/removing the question/posting your own answer?